# Showing $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ double covers $SO(1,3)$

Tags: group-theory

I have seen some proofs showing $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ double covers $SO(1,3)$ that go like this:

An arbitrary hermitian $2 \times 2$ matrix $X$ can be written as $X=X^\mu\sigma_{\mu}$, where $\sigma_{\mu}=(I,\sigma_i)$, from which follows that $\text{det} X=(X^0)^2-(X^1)^2-(X^2)^2-(X^3)^2$. 
We can define the action of $A\in SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ on $X$ via $X'=AXA^{\dagger}$, which leaves the determinant invariant and therefore can be identified with a $SO(1,3)$ transformation. Computing the kernel via $AXA^{\dagger}=X$ it follows by existence of the inverse that $AX=XA$ and by Schur's Lemma that $A=\lambda I$. Since $\text{det}A=1$ we deduce $A=\pm I$, thus obtaining the double cover.

My Question: Where is it used, that $A\in SL(2,\mathbb{C})$? I mean, the steps would still be correct if $A\in SU(2)$. The latter obviously doesn't make sense since there are only four and not six independent real components. But this should be used in the proof, right?

Comment: Pretty much that exact proof is used to show that $SU(2)$ double covers $SO(3)$.

Comment: Actually, $SL(2,C)$ does not cover $SO(1,3)$, it covers the identity component of the latter group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where is it used, that $A\in SL(2,\mathbb C)$?

In the last step, you assume $\det A =1$ which is true by definition iff $A \in SL(2,\mathbb C)$

> the steps would still be correct if $A\in SU(2)$

Yes, they still are, and it makes perfect sense because $SU(2)\subset SL(2,\mathbb C)$, or in other words if $A\in SU(2)$ then $A \in SL(2,\mathbb C)$ and a fortiori the steps are still correct.